# How to apply an ssl certificate to a Load Balancer Listener using OCI Certificates

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, oracle-cloud

I'm currently working on running a small personal server using OKE and a load balancer. My problem is as follows

1. I attached the OCI certificate to the load balancer listener, but it doesn't work, Only can move to 'https://...SomeDomain...' without any HTTPS protection(Red Line on the HTTPS part also description).
2. when I used ACM on AWS, there was definitely a domain verification process which register CNAME RECORD in DNS service. This seems to be missing with OCI, and I'm not sure how to do it.

Currently use imported certification, but since OCI certification is automatically renewal and free, i want use OCI's

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work" mean? Did you allow inbound https traffic? Is there something in the error logs?

Comment: @Lacek, Sorry for confused question. The point is How do i verify my domain in OCI Certification, similarly used in ACM on AWS . Surely in AWS ACM theres steps which can verify my domain. Such like register provided cname records in aws dns service